# How to Turn off App Suggestions From Launcher on Moto E4 Plus

Tags: settings, 7.1-nougat

This is my first question on this community. I was wondering is there a way to disable App Suggestion(Recently used) from the Launcher on Moto E4 Plus Running on Android 7.1.1

Also I wanna disable the google now which appears on the home screen when we swipe from left.

I have disabled them until Marshmallow. But I don't see any option to disable these 2 on Nougat 7.1.1

Comment: Use another launcher?

Comment: That would be the last move

Comment: If this don't help....[+VIDEO+ "swipe left toggle menu"](https://youtu.be/pd-qUBjPIc8) Then i don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have the same issue.  I can't remove app suggestions or toggle the swipe left setting off.  I tried what they did in the video but that option isn't there on my phone.  I am also using a Motorola Moto E4 Plus with Android Nougat 7.1.1.  Why is this working for some phone models and not for others?  Please can others comment here if this works for them or not and which phone model and Android version they are using?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Question 2:

- While on the Home Screen do a LONG PRESS/TOUCH and HOLD (Brings up the Background, Widgets, and Settings Menu)
- Select **SETTINGS** (Bottom Right)
- Select **SWIPE LEFT**
- Select option **NOTHING**

Comment: Sorry but I could see only "Allow Home screen rotation" toggle button and even that is disabled / grayed out.

Comment: Well i suppose the next Question would be which Android are you running

Comment: Android 7.1.1.  By the way, I have mentioned it in the question too

Comment: Next question is...  If it works for you or not then which phone model and Android version are you using?